# Convert linear ring to multilinestring and split into segments of x length

Tags: geotools

I have a linear ring created from points. I would then like to create a multilinestring from that and subsequently split that into segments of 7 metres each.

I tried the following but got 'LinearRing cannot be cast to class org.locationtech.jts.geom.MultiLineString'.

```
GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
LinearRing outer = gf.createLinearRing(coords.toArray(new Coordinate[] {}));
Polygon polygon = gf.createPolygon( outer, null );
MultiLineString mlslr = gf.createMultiLineString(new LineString[]{polygon.getExteriorRing()});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developped exactly what you describe [here](https://github.com/eurostat/JGiscoTools/blob/master/src/main/java/eu/europa/ec/eurostat/jgiscotools/algo/line/LittleThumblingDensifier.java). Feel free to reuse !

I called it "little thumbling densifier", as a reference to [this tale](https://www.bookreports.info/little-thumb-summary/). I have proposed to include it as part of [JTS](https://github.com/locationtech/jts) (see [here](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/pull/478)) so that it can also appear in GeoTools.